# Is there a better way to organize this, because right now Status = "TNC" is not Updating on my Excel sheet like I'd expect

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have inherited this product at work, and while it works without the statements I'm trying to add, I've been asked to try and capture this Status of TNC on some of the sheets. The module will execute and run all the way through no issues, however there are a few people that the table should update to Status = "TNC" that do not.

There are currently ElseIf statements in there. What's led me to this code is that if I used an If statement, or End If all so six and try to continue, it usually told me in another section that there was a Next with no For. Or at the end of the code attached the last End If was an End If with no If. I'm at a loss right now trying to get this to work.

```
SQUADRON = "23 AMU"
Worksheets(SQUADRON).Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 4
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table13").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table13").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10
RNum = 1
For RNum = 4 To 81

    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Range("B" & RNum).Value <> "" Then
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 19).Value = ""
        Pers_Name = Left(Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 2).Value, InStr(1, Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 2).Value, ",") + 2)
        'UPDATE LCS

        Set SEARCH_CELL = Sheet4.Range("C1:C150").Find(Pers_Name)
        If Not SEARCH_CELL Is Nothing Then
            'CONVENTIONAL
            If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 6).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 6).Value <> "D/C" Then
                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 7).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 7).Value <> "D/C" Then
                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 10).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 10).Value <> "D/C" Then
                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 13).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 13).Value <> "D/C" Then
                            If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 15).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 15).Value <> "D/C" Then
                                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 20).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 20).Value <> "D/C" Then
                                    Status = "C"
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

            ElseIf SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 6).Value = "D/C" Then
                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 7).Value = "D/C" Then
                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 10).Value = "D/C" Then
                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 13).Value = "D/C" Then
                            If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 15).Value = "D/C" Then
                                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 20).Value = "D/C" Then
                                    Status = "TNC"
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 6).Value = "" Then
                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 7).Value = "" Then
                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 10).Value = "" Then
                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 13).Value = "" Then
                            If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 15).Value = "" Then
                                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 20).Value = "" Then
                                    Status = "NC"
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 4).Value <> Status Then
            MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "Conventional Certification changed to " & Status
        End If
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 4).Value = Status

        'NUCLEAR
        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "D/C" Then
            If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "D/C" Then
                Status = "C"
            End If
        ElseIf SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 2).Value = "D/C" Then
                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value = "D/C" Then
                    Status = "TNC"
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then
            If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value = "" Then
                Status = "NC"
        End If
        If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 5).Value <> Status Then
            MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "Nuclear Certification changed to " & Status
        End If
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 5).Value = Status

        'S/M INT
        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 4).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 4).Value <> "D/C" Then
            Status = "C"
        Else
            Status = "NC"
        End If
        If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 6).Value <> Status Then
            MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "S/M Int Certification changed to " & Status
        End If
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 6).Value = Status

        'S/M EXT
        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "D/C" Then
            Status = "C"
        Else
            Status = "NC"
        End If
        If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 7).Value <> Status Then
            MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "S/M Ext Certification changed to " & Status
        End If
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 7).Value = Status
    Else
        answer = MsgBox(Pers_Name & " is not found on the LCS. Do you want to contniue checking crew numbers?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo)
        If answer = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
        'PRP STATUS
    Set SEARCH_CELL = Sheet5.Range("L12:L400").Find(Pers_Name)
    If Not SEARCH_CELL Is Nothing Then
        Status = SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 4).Value
        If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 18).Value <> Status Then
            MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "PRP Status changed to " & Status
        End If
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 18).Value = Status

        'DAS
        Status = SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, -6).Value
        If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 8).Value <> Status Then
            MsgBox Pers_Name & " Date Arrived on Station changed to " & Status
        End If
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 8).Value = Status

        'Lost
        Status = SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, -4).Value
        If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 9).Value <> Status Then
            If Status = 1 Then
                MsgBox Pers_Name & " is projected to be lost within a year."
            Else
                MsgBox Pers_Name & " is NOT projected to be lost within a year."
            End If
        End If
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 9).Value = Status

        'REMARKS
        Status = SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value
        If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 20).Value <> Status Then
            MsgBox Pers_Name & " Remarks changed to " & vbCrLf & Status
        End If
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 20).Value = Status

        If Not Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 20).Find("Profile") Is Nothing Then
            answer = MsgBox("Does " & Pers_Name & " profile limit his duty to loading?", vbYesNo)
            If answer = vbYes Then
                Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 19).Value = "Yes"
            ElseIf answer = vbNo Then
                Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 19).Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    Else
    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 18).ClearContents
    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 20).ClearContents
    answer = MsgBox(Pers_Name & " is not found on the Manning Doc. Do you want to contniue checking crew numbers?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo)
        If answer = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    End If
```

Previously this code had all the Initial If-Then statements, End If's and then a simple Else for Status = "NC" and the program worked as intended and updated the table accordingly. Like I said before I inherited this product, and it's messy however I've been trying to just fix what I can without essentially scrapping the entire thing and starting over from scratch. Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful.

```
SQUADRON = "23 AMU"
        Worksheets(SQUADRON).Select
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 4
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table13").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table13").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10
        RNum = 1
        For RNum = 4 To 81
            
            If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Range("B" & RNum).Value <> "" Then
                Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 19).Value = ""
                Pers_Name = Left(Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 2).Value, InStr(1, Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 2).Value, ",") + 2)
                'UPDATE LCS
                
                Set SEARCH_CELL = Sheet4.Range("C1:C150").Find(Pers_Name)
                If Not SEARCH_CELL Is Nothing Then
                    'CONVENTIONAL
                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 6).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 6).Value <> "D/C" Then
                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 7).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 7).Value <> "D/C" Then
                            If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 10).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 10).Value <> "D/C" Then
                                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 13).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 13).Value <> "D/C" Then
                                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 15).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 15).Value <> "D/C" Then
                                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 20).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 20).Value <> "D/C" Then
                                            Status = "C"
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                        
                    ElseIf SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 6).Value = "D/C" Then
                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 7).Value = "D/C" Then
                            If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 10).Value = "D/C" Then
                                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 13).Value = "D/C" Then
                                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 15).Value = "D/C" Then
                                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 20).Value = "D/C" Then
                                            Status = "TNC"
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 6).Value = "" Then
                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 7).Value = "" Then
                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 10).Value = "" Then
                            If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 13).Value = "" Then
                                If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 15).Value = "" Then
                                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 20).Value = "" Then
                                        Status = "NC"
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                    
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 4).Value <> Status Then
                        MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "Conventional Certification changed To " & Status
                    End If
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 4).Value = Status
                    
                    'NUCLEAR
                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "D/C" Then
                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "D/C" Then
                            Status = "C"
                        End If
                    ElseIf SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 2).Value = "D/C" Then
                        If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value = "D/C" Then
                            Status = "TNC"
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then
                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value = "" Then
                        Status = "NC"
                    End If
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 5).Value <> Status Then
                        MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "Nuclear Certification changed To " & Status
                    End If
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 5).Value = Status
                    
                    'S/M INT
                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 4).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 4).Value <> "D/C" Then
                        Status = "C"
                    Else
                        Status = "NC"
                    End If
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 6).Value <> Status Then
                        MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "S/M Int Certification changed To " & Status
                    End If
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 6).Value = Status
                    
                    'S/M EXT
                    If SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "" And SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "D/C" Then
                        Status = "C"
                    Else
                        Status = "NC"
                    End If
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 7).Value <> Status Then
                        MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "S/M Ext Certification changed To " & Status
                    End If
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 7).Value = Status
                Else
                    answer = MsgBox(Pers_Name & " Is Not found On the LCS. Do you want To contniue checking crew numbers?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo)
                    If answer = vbNo Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
                
                'PRP STATUS
                Set SEARCH_CELL = Sheet5.Range("L12:L400").Find(Pers_Name)
                If Not SEARCH_CELL Is Nothing Then
                    Status = SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 4).Value
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 18).Value <> Status Then
                        MsgBox Pers_Name & vbCrLf & "PRP Status changed To " & Status
                    End If
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 18).Value = Status
                    
                    'DAS
                    Status = SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, -6).Value
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 8).Value <> Status Then
                        MsgBox Pers_Name & " Date Arrived On Station changed To " & Status
                    End If
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 8).Value = Status
                    
                    'Lost
                    Status = SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, -4).Value
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 9).Value <> Status Then
                        If Status = 1 Then
                            MsgBox Pers_Name & " Is projected To be lost within a year."
                        Else
                            MsgBox Pers_Name & " Is Not projected To be lost within a year."
                        End If
                    End If
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 9).Value = Status
                    
                    'REMARKS
                    Status = SEARCH_CELL.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 20).Value <> Status Then
                        MsgBox Pers_Name & " Remarks changed To " & vbCrLf & Status
                    End If
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 20).Value = Status
                    
                    If Not Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 20).Find("Profile") Is Nothing Then
                        answer = MsgBox("Does " & Pers_Name & " profile limit his duty To loading?", vbYesNo)
                        If answer = vbYes Then
                            Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 19).Value = "Yes"
                        ElseIf answer = vbNo Then
                            Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 19).Value = ""
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 18).ClearContents
                    Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 20).ClearContents
                    answer = MsgBox(Pers_Name & " Is Not found On the Manning Doc. Do you want To contniue checking crew numbers?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo)
                    If answer = vbNo Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
                ' 1 MAN DLC/DLCN LIST UPDATE
                If RNum = 4 Or RNum = 10 Or RNum = 16 Or RNum = 22 Or RNum = 28 Or RNum = 34 Or RNum = 40 Or RNum = 46 Or RNum = 52 Or RNum = 58 Or RNum = 64 Or RNum = 70 Or RNum = 76 Then
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 10).Value = 1 Then
                        Worksheets("CREW CARDS").Range("K" & DLC1).Value = Pers_Name
                        DLC1 = DLC1 + 1
                    End If
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 11).Value = 1 Then
                        Worksheets("CREW CARDS").Range("T" & DLCN1).Value = Pers_Name
                        DLCN1 = DLCN1 + 1
                    End If
                End If
                ' 2 MAN DLC/DLCN LIST UPDATE
                If RNum = 5 Or RNum = 11 Or RNum = 17 Or RNum = 23 Or RNum = 29 Or RNum = 35 Or RNum = 41 Or RNum = 47 Or RNum = 53 Or RNum = 59 Or RNum = 65 Or RNum = 71 Or RNum = 77 Then
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 10).Value = 1 Then
                        Worksheets("CREW CARDS").Range("M" & DLC2).Value = Pers_Name
                        DLC2 = DLC2 + 1
                    End If
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 11).Value = 1 Then
                        Worksheets("CREW CARDS").Range("V" & DLCN2).Value = Pers_Name
                        DLCN2 = DLCN2 + 1
                    End If
                End If
                ' 3 MAN DLC/DLCN LIST UPDATE
                If RNum = 6 Or RNum = 12 Or RNum = 18 Or RNum = 24 Or RNum = 30 Or RNum = 36 Or RNum = 42 Or RNum = 48 Or RNum = 54 Or RNum = 60 Or RNum = 66 Or RNum = 72 Or RNum = 78 Then
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 10).Value = 1 Then
                        Worksheets("CREW CARDS").Range("O" & DLC3).Value = Pers_Name
                        DLC3 = DLC3 + 1
                    End If
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 11).Value = 1 Then
                        Worksheets("CREW CARDS").Range("X" & DLCN3).Value = Pers_Name
                        DLCN3 = DLCN3 + 1
                    End If
                End If
                ' 4 MAN DLC/DLCN LIST UPDATE
                If RNum = 7 Or RNum = 13 Or RNum = 19 Or RNum = 25 Or RNum = 31 Or RNum = 37 Or RNum = 43 Or RNum = 49 Or RNum = 55 Or RNum = 61 Or RNum = 67 Or RNum = 73 Or RNum = 79 Then
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 10).Value = 1 Then
                        Worksheets("CREW CARDS").Range("Q" & DLC4).Value = Pers_Name
                        DLC4 = DLC4 + 1
                    End If
                    If Worksheets(SQUADRON).Cells(RNum, 11).Value = 1 Then
                        Worksheets("CREW CARDS").Range("Z" & DLCN4).Value = Pers_Name
                        DLCN4 = DLCN4 + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=1
        Next RNum
        
        answer = MsgBox("Do you want To open the Load Schedule To update projected ICERTs?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
        If answer = vbYes Then
            URL = Worksheets("WS").Cells(50, 1).Value
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink URL
            
        End If
        Worksheets("MOC Slide").Select
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Worksheets("MOC Slide").Range("C5").Select
        
        UserForm1.Show
        
        MsgBox "Crew Numbers Updated", vbInformation
        
        'if LCS not updated
    Else
        MsgBox "Please update the LCS", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

This is how the code looks now after running through the automateexcel. However the TNC status is still never updated on my Excel table. I've ensured that it is formatted correctly and calls to the correct cell. I feel like I'm still missing something obvious here.

Comment: The last `End If` should be `Next RNum`. 
It's easy to identify the mismatch if you keep your code well-organized with proper indentation.  Try https://www.automateexcel.com/vba-code-indenter/#copy.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I'm going to give that a shot in the morning and I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Try [this "Pretty Print" VBA](https://davetallett26.github.io/prettyprint.html)